# I can't get Linq Order By to work on a Sub-List

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate to pull out pages with their subpages to create a menu structure on my page. Everything pulls out fine, I'm getting all the correct information, but I cannot get the OrderBy to work on the subpage list at all. I've added in the order figure and can output it on screen without issue, I just can't get it to sort by it!

```
menu.MenuItems = _session.Query<Page>().Where(a => a.IncludeInMenu).Where(b => b.ParentPage == null).OrderBy(c => c.MenuOrder).Select(d => new MenuItem
        {
            Route = "/" + d.Route,
            Name = d.Name,
            Current = (d.Id == id),
            Clickable = d.Clickable,
            SubItems = d.SubPages.Where(e => e.IncludeInMenu).OrderBy(f => f.MenuOrder).Select(g => new SubItem
            {
                Id = g.Id,
                Route = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Redirect) ? g.Redirect : g.Route,
                Name = g.Name,
                Order = g.MenuOrder,
                Text = g.MetaDescription,
                Redirect = g.RedirectType
            }).OrderBy(h => h.Order).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

The order by in the top level appears to be working fine. I tried both doing the same thing again in the sub level, and ordering after the fact with the newly created Order field. But neither works. Page.MenuOrder and SubItem.Order are both just in fields:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public bool Current { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Clickable { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? Redirect { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

I'm outputting in my view like so:

```
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>@foreach (var MenuItem in Model.Menu.MenuItems)
                {
                <li>
                    <a href="@MenuItem.Route">@MenuItem.Name</a>
                    @if (MenuItem.SubItems != null && MenuItem.SubItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var SubItem in MenuItem.SubItems)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@SubItem.Route">
                                    @SubItem.Name
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                    }
                </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

In my database, the IDs of the items also order the items in the same way as the ordering does, so I have no idea where it's getting the order it's choosing from either. They are coming out as 3, 1, 4, 2.

If anyone has any idea why this sub-list won't output in the order I'm setting, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What database technology are you using? EF 6.x, EF Core 2, EF Core 2.1+, EF Core 3.x?

Comment: the first order by in the sub pages is irrelevant d.SubPages.Where(e => e.IncludeInMenu).OrderBy(f => f.MenuOrder) because you order later again.
Could you provide sample data? I checked the query and don't see any obvious mistake.
You could log the SQL generated by the query, then it is easier to see what is wrong

Comment: @NetMage EF 6.0 and its MySQL 5.7

Comment: @PeterFromCologne I knew I didn't need them both, I was just keeping both in so you could easily see what I'd tried. What's the best way to log the SQL generated, I don't think I've done that before, I tend to just use what I can see during debug, which doesn't translate easily to a single output. The menu order is correct is I look at just the query output, it only goes wrong once I transfer it into the menu model. It remains the same if I remove all the subpage order by clauses.

Comment: What if you switch to client processing by putting `AsEnumerable()` just before the first `Select`, and remove the extra `OrderBy`, leaving the last one?

Comment: wait... you tagged and mentioned NHibernate, then in the comments you mention EF 6.0. Which is it?

Comment: @mxmissile sorry was a bit on autopilot there. I'm using NHibernate 5.2. I had some old references to EF which I've now removed.

Comment: @NetMage that did it! Thank you so much. Any clues as to why? And did you want to answer the question?

Comment: @VampiricMonkey My guess would be that the SQL translation is ignoring the `OrderBy` in the sub-query, something EF Core occasionally does when combined with other operations (`GroupBy`?). The `AsEnumerable` causes a switch to client side execution of the `Select`. This may pull over more fields than needed from the table, you could put a flat `Select` before the `AsEnumerable` to restrict the fields returned.